# Oracle 11gR2 expdp table converted to CSV from Linux

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux

With Oracle expdp,  I can export the tables I want with

```
expdp INCLUDE=TABLE:table1,table2,table3
```

I need a way to convert this into CSV on a linux machine. I've seen Windows tools but don't know how good they are and this needs to work from linux command line/ bash script.

Is this possible?

Comment: How does the file look? (I'm not a dba) Give me a head on one file.

Comment: @FlorinGhita expdp generated files are binary & not human-readable

Answer (score 2):

No its not possible with expdp, you need to use utl_file to solve this

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:88212348059

Comment: Note that the linked discussion goes back some 11 years.  The utilities supplied for this purpose have changed over the years.

Comment: You'd be better off using an external table

Comment: @Phil he want to write outside the database some tables. How can be useful an external table? Can you write it?

Comment: Actually, I tell a lie. You can't write to external tables. I really shouldn't post on here when sleepy! :)   Are you on Windows or Unix?

Comment: I'm not the poster. You are really sleepy :))

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sqlplus` and spool the output. You can find info about the syntax on the internet, searching sqlplus tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

login oracle linux

sqlplus / sysdba

spool "/home/oracle/file.csv";

SELECT  * from dual;